# Amazon Web Services S3 How to 'Obtain the 'PoolID' constant.'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

The AWS readme tells you to:

"1. In the [Amazon Cognito console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/), use Amazon Cognito to create a new identity pool. Obtain the `PoolID` constant. Make sure the [role](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#roles) has full permissions for the bucket you created."

No problem creating the pool but I can't for the life of me find the PoolID constant. It must be blindingly obvious but it's eluding me.

Comment: If you can't locate it in the console then use the awscli (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-identity/list-identity-pools.html).

Comment: Many thanks jarmod.  I finally found it.  It is NOT obvious and is well and truly buried. :)

Comment: Good to hear. Might be worth answering your own question and marking it as the answer for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

- If you created the pool through the console, it's included in the sample code at the end of the wizard.
- In any case, that same sample code is visible via a link the left pane once you visit the pool from the console.
- It's also visible if you click 'Edit Identity Pool' once you visit the pool page from the console.
- Finally, it's in the URL if you visit the pool page from the console.

Sample code for android looks like this:

`// Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
    getApplicationContext(),
    "us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", // Identity Pool ID
    Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
);`

Comment: Thanks everyone. Following Jarmod's suggestion here's my 2c on finding the ID.  1) start at account page https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?#/account

2) select ‘services’ then ‘cognito'

3) the page displays your identity pools

4) if you click on the name of the identity pool you are interested in, this is a link that to takes you to the info on that identity pool

5) then either:
a) select ‘Sample Code’ on LHS navigation panel - the Identity Pool ID is in the sample code

b) select link on top RHS of page to ‘edit identity pool’ - this pagee has the identity pool name and pool ID